# TypeError: Cannot find function rangeToObjects in object [object Object]. (line 4, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

my Code.gs is:

```
    function createPages(){
  var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl('https://sites.google.com/site/typsetgraphics/website-assistance-services/web-graphics');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14_W42RTQNoTZhl7DodhjJAiZ9kPp4zHxFcI5jVmxPNQ/edit#gid=0').getSheets()[0];  
  var productDetails = ObjApp.rangeToObjects(ss.getDataRange().getValues());
  for (var i=0; i<productDetails.length; i++){ 
    if (productDetails[i].productPage != "") continue;  
    var page = site.createWebPage(productDetails[i].title, 
                                  ObjApp.camelString(productDetails[i].title), 
                                  '<img src="'+productDetails[i].imageUrl+
                                  '" align="left"/><p>'+productDetails[i].description);
    productDetails[i].productPage = page.getUrl();  
  }
  var headers = ss.getRange(1,1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  
  var values = ObjApp.objectToArray(headers, productDetails); 
  ss.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}


function randomString() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14_W42RTQNoTZhl7DodhjJAiZ9kPp4zHxFcI5jVmxPNQ').getSheets()[0];
  var randomArray = new Array();
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var string_length = 10;
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()-1;
  for (var j=0; j<lastRow; j++){
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    randomArray.push([randomstring]);
  }
  ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 1).setValues(randomArray);
}
```

and line 4 specifically is:

var productDetails = ObjApp.rangeToObjects(ss.getDataRange().getValues());

this is all directly out of James Ferreira's book, Chapter 5, and I only changed the filename to adapt it to my project, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Not to mention the fact that I'm new to Google Apps scripts, and Javascript writing. Can anyone out there assist?

Comment: Did you remember to add `ObjService` as a library resource for your project? See [Using a Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#useLibrary).

Comment: In fact that may have been the issue because I didn't add it correctly at first. Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score -1):

Please Install an open source library first. it can be found on `ObjService` on the Google Script Examples site. 
In the Script Editor click Resources, select libraries, add a library  `"MTeYmpfWgqPbiBkVHnpgnM9kh30YExdAc"`, select version is 5, click save.